# Custom nested cols in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I got a tough requirement to make a layout like this image with Bootstrap 3:

[image: expecting layout]

Currently I can make it like this:

[image: this]

Here is my sample html layout: https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/4etczrwx/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:500px;background-color:red;">
            images
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix col-sm-6"  style="height:100px;background-color:yellow;">
            text dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdg
            text dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdg
            text dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdg
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3" style="height:200px;background-color:blue;">
            keyfeature
            <ul>
                <li>testest 1</li>
                <li>testest 2</li>
                <li>testest 3</li>
                <li>testest 4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3" style="height:600px;background-color:gray;">
            Price tab here
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-9" style="height:800px;background-color:green;">
            Configurator here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think I'am missing something to make the green col?
or should I use push/pull to make it work as my expectation?

Comment: you may try masonry http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html :)

Comment: Thanks @DenPat , our system is using bootstrap3. is it compatible with bootstrap3 or it's totally different css framework?

Comment: it's not css framework , it can be used with jQuery , you may take look at their codepen example too : http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/mIkhq

Comment: this is really nice, let me see if it can solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the `float: right;` property to the gray block when the screen width becomes `786px` or more. I've defined a new special class `.pull-sm-right` for this purpose.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pull-sm-right {
    float: right !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:500px;background-color:red;">
            images
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix col-sm-6"  style="height:100px;background-color:yellow;">
            text dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdg
            text dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdg
            text dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdg
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3" style="height:200px;background-color:blue;">
            keyfeature
            <ul>
                <li>testest 1</li>
                <li>testest 2</li>
                <li>testest 3</li>
                <li>testest 4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3 pull-sm-right" style="height:600px;background-color:gray;">
            Price tab here
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-9" style="height:800px;background-color:green;">
            Configurator here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if this is fixed layout than you can just add margin-top:-200px to that green section like this : jsfiddle.net/4etczrwx/1

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6" style="height:500px;background-color:red;">
            images
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix col-xs-6" style="height:100px;background-color:yellow;">
            text dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdg text dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdg text dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdgtext dsgsg sdg sdgsdg
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-3" style="height:200px;background-color:blue;">
            keyfeature
            <ul>
                <li>testest 1</li>
                <li>testest 2</li>
                <li>testest 3</li>
                <li>testest 4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-3" style="height:600px;background-color:gray;">
            Price tab here
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-9" style="height:800px;background-color:green;margin-top:-300px;">
            Configurator here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Cheers !

Comment: Thank you but it's a dynamic content, especially gray area, they will be floating when scrolling.